# Identifying information contained in Adobe files

Tags: security, adobe-photoshop, privacy, metadata, adobe-premiere

For many file formats, there are typical types of metadata that one may want to erase if they do not want personally-identifying information to be associated with the file. EXIF data in image files is a typical example.

I have recently begun to use Adobe Creative Cloud for making images and movies (in particular, Premiere, Indesign, Photoshop, Media Encoder, and After Effects).

Is there any data in files produced by these Adobe programs that could connect the files to your Adobe account or computer, and if so how one could remove this information?

I would like to clarify that I am particularly interested in Adobe specific metadata, for example something in an mp4 file which is unique to the Adobe account that the Adobe premier application used to make the mp4 is connected to.

Comment: Why do you want to know that? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/271683/identifying-information-contained-in-adobe-files

Comment: If you are a Bellingcat researcher we may be more likely to help you than if you want to spread photoshopped revenge porn. It would be trivial for a big company like Adobe to hide something similar to a serial inside every image or movie created by their software; and it would be very hard to detect unless you have very specific technical know-how or inside information. [Digital watermarking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_watermarking) is pretty damn advanced these days.

Answer (score 1):

You can't possibly know if Adobe software adds anything to the files without seeing the source code or analyzing lots of files, as it could be even coded to only mark 1 out of 100 of them or the ones that are edited many times. I'd say it's very unlikely they would be doing that without informing users, though. Maybe as some sort of anti-piracy measure, but that doesn't really help them to track people down.

What's surely known to public is that:

- different apps have various settings that allow you to add metadata, e.g. Acrobat Reader has `Preferences` -> `Identity`. But if you didn't add anything, this shouldn't concern you.
- you can check basic metadata with various apps. You used `.mp4` example - that can be checked with ffprobe from [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) executables, like:

```
ffprobe -show_formats -show_streams file.mp4
```

Or you could use more metadata-related [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/):

```
exiftool file.mp4
```